# How come when I import of two functions from the same module, the import works only for one the two?

Tags: python, virtualenv, hpc

**Intro**
I am running a python script on an cluster. I run everything in virtualenv and in the code I am importing two functions from the same module (written in SC_module.py):

ex. SC_module.py

```
def funA():

def funB():
```

In the script script.py I have the following import

```
from SC_module import funA,funB
```

when I run the code on the HPC I get import error funB cannot be found. If I type

```
from SC_module import funA
```

everything works fine. 
If I run `python3` from the command line and run

```
from SC_module import funA,funB
```

everything works and fun(B) is imported.

**Question**
The only difference between funA() and funB() is that have been coded in two different days.
*NB*: If I add an new function to the module it will not be loaded when starting the process but will be imported if I will use the terminal.
Is there something I miss in the loading of the module in the cluster?

Thanks

Comment: Is your cluster long-running? Because if so, you'll have to re-import your module, which is kind of a pain.

Comment: "The only difference between funA() and funB() is that have been coded in two different days." <-- That sounds like your answer. Apparently the version of `SC_module` on the server does not have `funB`, while your local copy does.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The error happens also when I completely remove the code and install a new version (with both fun) and re-start all the processes.

Comment: @WayneWerner the process will be running for a long time but I have also been testing using the interactive mode or running mock processes for short time.

Comment: What happens if you `import SC_module` and access the functions from there?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") ***MUST include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Check for circular imports.

Comment: @user2357112  I was a problem with a circular input that somehow was masking the function I needed to load.

Answer (score 0):

Remove file: `SC_module.pyc`, and try run it again.

Comment: Done it and unfortunately doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you print out your import path list and check that they match what you think they are, in both environments:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for d in sys.path:
...  print d
```

Plus:

```
import SC_module
print dir(SC_module)
```

to see what functions are in the imported module.
There must be a mismatch somewhere!